# executing if else statement by probability

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

I have a program that looks something like this. i would like to run my if else query by probability.

```
int main() {
    int probability = 70;   //<-- 70% probability to run if statement

    for (int i = 0; i < 5e5; i++){
        if (???){      
            ...
        }
        else {         
            ...
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Get a random number between 0 and 100. Then test if it's less than `chance`

Comment: Do you want it to really be by chance? Or exactly 70/30 but in a random order?

Comment: 70 times for 100 runs is not "chance". It's exact.

Comment: Sorry I changed it. i just want a probability that the if statement will be executed

Comment: The most portable solution (but potentially not very random) is `if (rand() % 100 < chance)`. On platforms where it's supported, `if (arc4random_uniform(100) < chance)` will give better randomness. And some platforms provide a `random` function, which is better than `rand`, but not as good as `arc4random_uniform`.

Answer (score 1):

As @user3386109 pointed out, `if(rand() % 100 < chance)` is probably more then sufficient. As [explained in the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html), when the random number generated is not a multiple of 100, here, this method causes some numbers to appear more than others. If it falls on the range where it makes a difference, the easiest thing is to draw another number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* rand() */
#include <time.h> /* clock() */

/** http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html */
static int rand_0_99(void) {
    unsigned int x = (RAND_MAX + 1u) / 100;
    unsigned int y = x * 100;
    unsigned int r;
    do r = rand();
    while(r >= y);
    return r / x;
}

int main(void) {
    size_t i, cumulate = 0;
    const size_t replicas = 1000000;
    const int chance_100 = 70;

    /* Seed the linear congruential generator with the time. */
    srand((unsigned)clock());
    for(i = 0; i < replicas; i++) {
        const int decision = rand_0_99() < chance_100;
        if(decision) cumulate++;
    }
    printf("P(r < %d/100) = %lu/%lu\n",
        chance_100, (unsigned long)cumulate, (unsigned long)replicas);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is overkill, but may be needed, especially when 100 is close to `RAND_MAX`.